# Ruby on Rails asset organisation folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I'm using ruby on rails 5. What is the difference app/assets, lib/assets and vendor/asset?

If I write my own js scripts should they be included in the app/assets? How about if I use a bootstrap library where should I put it at?

And regardless which folder they are in, i am able to access them using `javascript_include_tag`? Example:

```
javascript_include_tag "xmlhr"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

> - app/assets is for assets that are owned by the application, such as custom images, JavaScript files or stylesheets.
> - lib/assets is for your own libraries' code that doesn't really fit into the scope of the application or those libraries which are shared across applications.
> - vendor/assets is for assets that are owned by outside entities, such as code for JavaScript plugins and CSS frameworks. Keep in mind that third party code with references to other files also processed by the asset Pipeline (images, stylesheets, etc.), will need to be rewritten to use helpers like asset_path.

Me, I only use app and vendor. My stuff goes to app, naturally. And 3rd party stuff (jquery plugins, bootstrap themes and whatnot) goes to vendor.

Answer (score 1):

> app/assets

It should include all the assets written by you and only relevant to your project.

> lib/assets

It should include all the assets which are created by you but can be extracted to be used by another project.

> vendor/assets

It should include all the assets downloaded/purchased from third party like Bootstrap.